# Having multiple sessionFactory instances

Tags: oracle, hibernate

I am porting a legacy application to hibernate 5 and I'm having trouble with the login phase. Here's how it works (I can't change that):

- user initially connects to oracle DB with a generic login/password (same for all users)
- then user runs a "login" stored procedure and enters a unique password as parameter
- the procedure returns a specific Oracle DB username/password to the user
- user disconnects from DB and reconnects using the credentials given by the stored procedure

I currently create one instance of sessionFactory per connected user, but I'm worried that this will impact performance. Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14411860/why-use-only-one-sessionfactory-object-per-application. It explains the merits for having to have implemented the Factory design pattern.

Comment: Yes I have thank you. But how to have one session factory instance with different login/passwords?

Comment: This is essentially the same issue as here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520583/hibernate-multiple-users-dynamically-changing and there doesn't seem to be any other way than use multiple SessionFactories...

Comment: > but I'm worried that this will impact performance. 

How do you know that it would impact performance? Having said that, if you configure your `SessionFactory` properly, nothing to worried about it.

> Is there a better way to do this?

No. And as mentioned by others and links above, one user per `SessionFactory` is correct approach to your requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate [Multitenancy](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#multitenacy) with "Separate database" strategy would work even if you are actually connecting to the same database but different credentials.
[MultiTenantConnectionProvider](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/engine/jdbc/connections/spi/MultiTenantConnectionProvider.html) must be specified to return connection with right username and password.